# Searching array for multiple value

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I've got an array containing

```
"1", "2", "3", "4"
```

And I use `array_rand` to select one of those numbers randomly five times. Then I want to count how many of the result of `array_rand` that have been chosen multiple times like the number 2 got chosen 2 times and number 3 got chosen 2 times.

I have tested doing this

```
$array = array($kort1[$rand_kort1[0]], $kort1[$rand_kort2[0]], $kort1[$rand_kort3[0]], $kort1[$rand_kort4[0]], $kort1[$rand_kort5[0]]);
$bank = array_count_values($array);
if (in_array("2", $bank)) {
    echo "You got one pair";
} elseif(in_array("2", $bank) && (???)) {
    echo "You got two pair";
}
```

it will tell me "You got one pair" if one of those numbers were randomly chosen 2 times but my problem is I don't know how to make it say "You got two pairs" if 2 of those numbers were chosen 2 times.
the result of `$bank` could be

```
 [4] => 1 [3] => 2 [1] => 2
```

Comment: Is `[3] => 2 [1] => 3 ` considered two pairs?

Comment: @Erwin [3] => 2 [1] => 2   thats two pairs and the code should ignore the last number

Comment: How bout four of a kind? Is that also considered two pairs? e.g. `[3] => 4 [1] => 1`

Comment: Updated my answer with a one line solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_filter to appy a function to each element of your array

```
$bank=array(4 => 1, 3 => 2, 1 => 2); // Your array
function pairs($var) {
    return($var === 2); // returns value if the input integer equals 2
} 
$pairs=count(array_filter($bank, "pairs")); // Apply the function to all elements of the array and get the number of times 2 was found
if ($pairs === 1)  
{
echo "you got one pair";
}
if ($pairs === 2) {
echo "you got two pairs";
}
```

**EDIT**

Thought of this one liner later:

```
$pairs=count(array_diff($bank, array(1,3,4)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: (This will work even if your array has more than 4 values)

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($bank as $key=>$value) {
    if ($value === 2) {
        $count++;
    }
}

if ($count) {
    $s = $count > 1 ? 's' : '';
    echo "You got $count pair$s";
}
```

It will show an output like `You got 1 pair`. If you want to use words (like you mentioned in your question), you can use [NumberFormatter class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php)